# Return 2nd Level List in Java Lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I need to return the matching object based on condition. I have this 3 level list and I need to return an object in the second list.

Codes sample below.

```
firstLevelList.getMySecondList().stream()
               .flatMap(secondLevelList -> secondLevelList.getThirdLevelList().stream())
               .filter(thirdLevelList -> thirdLevelList.getMyConditionObject() == "test")
```

Now I am lost, I need to return the second level list object like secondLevelList.getTest();

Hope someone can help.

Comment: in this specific case comparing strings with  `==` would give you unexpected results. Also, it's unclear what your intention is here. could you show some sample data and what the expected outcome should be? do you want a single object or a list of objects?

Comment: how many value you want to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you need to get those second level elements where they might contain any thirdLevelList with the given condition

```
 firstLevelList.getMySecondList()
               .stream()
               .filter(x -> x.getThirdLevelList().stream().anyMatch(y -> y.getMyConditionObject().equals("test"))
               .map(x -> x.getTest())
               .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    firstLevelList.getMySecondList().stream()
            .filter(secondLevelList -> secondLevelList.getThirdLevelList().stream()
                    .anyMatch(thirdLevelList -> thirdLevelList.getMyConditionObject() == "test"))
            .map(secondLevelList -> secondLevelList.getTest())
            .collect(toList());
```